# Login Loop after upgrading 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: 16.04, loop-device

Recently I upgraded my OS to 16.04 from 14.04. Now I can login using root user. However I could not login using the user I created during installation. I tried a lot troubleshooting using Nvidia driver purging and reinstalling. Also tried to change the ownership of x authority folder. Still the problem is not solved. It is irritatingly looping again and again to the login screen. I could also login using guest user. However only login is not possible for my specific user. please suggest me the best possible solution. I have HP ProBook laptop.

Comment: Which graphics card and which drivers have you tried installing/purging/re-installing?

Comment: Log into root user. In `terminal` do `ls -al /home/your_username/.*thority`, copy/paste that output into your question, and I'll take a look. Ping me at `@heynnema` or I may miss your response.

Comment: My problem is solved.